# Do nucleons experience friction?

Tags: nuclear-physics, friction

I know that friction occurs because of imperfect surfaces rub against each other, and to my knowledge this occurs on the molecular level. However, since nucleons have spin, I was wondering if, since they are pressed together in the nucleus with nuclear force, if a noticeable force of friction is present. If there is, then wouldn't that mean that the surfaces of the nucleons are not only imperfect, but are made up of way smaller particles as well to create these imperfections?

I may be completely wrong, of course, but it is of interest to me nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Particles interact through fundamental forces. Friction is not a fundamental force, it's a complex form of electromagnetic interaction at the micro and the nano scales. That aside, you cannot think of particles as usual objects; their spins do not translate into rotation of ball-like objects.